# How to develop a LibreOffice extension in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, libreoffice, uno

I'm currently trying to develop a LibreOffice extension using Java 7 and Eclipse Juno in Ubuntu 12.10. From the documentation I've found, I know there is an Eclipse plugin, and a LibreOffice SDK which should be compatible with OpenOffice. I installed LibreOffice and its SDK from `apt-get`; the plugin from http://api.openoffice.org/Projects/EclipseIntegration/dev-update/site.xml.

When I try to create a new UNO-IDL project in Eclipse, the plugin asks for the SDK and OOo paths. However, neither LibreOffice SDK nor LibreOffice installation dirs work! About the SDK, the plugin complains that it needs at least SDK version 2.0.4, but I'm using LibreOffice 3.6.0.

Is there any way of configuring or installing LibreOffice or the plugin so that I can create a UNO-IDL project in Eclipse Juno.

Also, it has been difficult to find documentation and tutorials on how to develop LibreOffice extensions. Is there a detailed beginners' tutorial on how to develop a LibreOffice extension using Eclipse?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is about requiring at least SDK version 2.0.4. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.
I had the same problem and the reason for the error is that their provided eclipse plugin is too old.
http://www.flattermann.net/2009/06/openofficeorg-extension-development-with-eclipse-ooeclipse/

Comment: I'm now using OpenOffice and Netbeans plugin to do the developing. I had to tweak some things myself, but I got it working. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: @ArielD.MoyaSequeira I need your help to setup Netbeans and Office to create extension. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse plugin has recently been updated to work with latest LibreOffice and Eclipse versions, check https://github.com/LibreOffice/loeclipse.

There is also a starter extension which contains all the boilerplate code needed to create a new LibreOffice extension, including a guide how to setup the development environment with the Eclipse plugin: https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension

Comment: That's good news! I'll take a look at it when I get the chance.