# Setting up "Path to OOo installation" LibreOffice SDK configuration on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, libreoffice

I'm try to develop a LibreOffice extension in Java using Eclipse Kepler on MacOSX 10.9.1, but I can't manage to set up the path to the LibreOffice.app installation.

Can someone please give me a hint on how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751422/how-to-develop-a-libreoffice-extension-in-eclipse) might help

Comment: Thank you! I took a look at the post above but I'm already using the newer plugin as answered, which can be found at http://www.flattermann.net/2009/06/openofficeorg-extension-development-with-eclipse-ooeclipse/

Comment: I too need to set up in mac please suggest any solution, it will be helpful for me.